# Android :How to getText from Edittext in side ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

i have problem getting text from edittext inside listview when im in last edittext in the list problem in getting data of that edittext ,because when change focus of that edittext onfocuschangelistner is not getting call and data of that edittext is not store in my collection variable .

So any one have any solution plz suggest me

My code is here

```
    public class YourAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    protected static final String TAG = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> c = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    Context context;
    JSONArray getArray_Meter_Reading;
    HashMap<String, String> previous_Meter_Reading;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>> getReading = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>>();
    Map<String,Integer> CurrentReading  = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    int i, previousMeterReading, CurrentMeterReading, Cumulative;
    View v;
    EditText Caption;
    public static HashMap<Integer, String> myList = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    public YourAdapter(Context context, int layout,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> c, String[] from, int[] to,
            JSONArray getArray_Meter_Reading) {
        super(context, c, layout, from, to);
        this.c = c;
        this.context = context;
        this.v = null;
        this.Caption = null;
        this.getArray_Meter_Reading = getArray_Meter_Reading;

        for (i = 0; i < getArray_Meter_Reading.length(); i++) {
            myList.put(i, "");
        }

    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        final EditText ed_Current = (EditText) view
                .findViewById(R.id.ed_Current);
        ed_Current.setTag(position);

        ed_Current.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

            public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean arg1) {

                int tag1 = (Integer) arg0.getTag();
                myList.put(tag1, ed_Current.getText().toString().trim());
                previous_Meter_Reading = new HashMap<String, String>();


                if (v == null) {
                    v = arg0;

                    int tag = (Integer) arg0.getTag();
                    Caption = (EditText) arg0;

                    previous_Meter_Reading = c.get(tag);
                    String getPreviousReading = previous_Meter_Reading
                            .get("previousMeterReading");
                    String CumulativeIndex = previous_Meter_Reading
                            .get("Cumulative");
                    previousMeterReading = Integer.parseInt(getPreviousReading);
                    Cumulative = Integer.parseInt(CumulativeIndex);
                }


                if (v != arg0) {

                    if (!Caption.getText().toString().equals("")
                            && Cumulative == 1) {

                        int tag = ((Integer) arg0.getTag());
                        CurrentMeterReading = Integer.valueOf(Caption.getText()
                                .toString());


                        //CurrentReading.put("Tag"+ tag, CurrentMeterReading);
                        //if(CurrentReading.containsKey("Tag"+ tag)){
                         //  
                        //  Log.d("Contains","Tag"+ tag );
                        //  CurrentReading.remove("Tag"+ tag);
                        //}
                    //  }else{
                        //  
                             CurrentReading.put("Tag"+ tag,CurrentMeterReading);
                        //}
                        //getReading.add(CurrentReading);
                             Log.d("CurrentReading",CurrentReading.toString() );
                        if (CurrentMeterReading < previousMeterReading) {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                    context);
                            builder.setTitle("WARNING");
                            builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
                            builder.setMessage("Current value cannot be less than Previous value for metre");
                            builder.setPositiveButton("ok",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                        public void onClick(
                                                DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int which) {

                                            //Caption.requestFocus();

                                        }
                                    });

                            AlertDialog diag = builder.create();
                            diag.show();

                            // Caption.requestFocus();
                            // v = null;
                            // Caption = null;
                        } 
                    }else {
                            if (Cumulative == 0

                                && !Caption.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                int tag = ((Integer) arg0.getTag());
                            // int tag1 = ((Integer) arg0.getTag());
                            CurrentMeterReading = Integer.valueOf(Caption
                                    .getText().toString());


                            CurrentReading.put("Tag" +tag, CurrentMeterReading);
                            if(CurrentReading.containsKey("Tag"+ tag)){
                                CurrentReading.put("Tag"+ tag,CurrentMeterReading);
                            }
                            //getReading.add(CurrentReading);
                        }
                        }

                    //Caption.requestFocus();
                    v = null;
                    Caption = null;
                }

            }
        });

        ed_Current.setText(myList.get(position));
        return view;
    }
}

and my xml which im binding with listview using simpleadapter

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="6dip"
    android:paddingTop="4dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_Meter_Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:width="140dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_Previous"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:width="100dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ed_Current"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext|actionDone"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:numeric="integer"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:width="100dp" >
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go through below link you will get the Idea :

http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/android-focusable-edittext-inside-listview/